# How To De-Structure This JavaScript Properly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm really struggling with des-tructuring syntax for examples like what I have below. This code does what I want:

```
const data = my();
const currentCheckBoxListArray = data.checkBoxListArray.currentCheckBoxListArray;
```

I tried this and get a syntax error:

```
const {
   data: {
             checkBoxListArray: { currentCheckBoxListArray },
         },
   } = my();
```

Any suggestions to how to think about this so I can figure it out myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are destructuring one level too deeply.

```
const { checkBoxListArray: { currentCheckBoxListArray } } = data;
```

Comment: Thanks @kinduser. Maybe I am getting closer to being able to do this without having to think so hard.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this,

const { checkBoxListArray: { currentCheckBoxListArray } } = my();